# How to duplicate existing column but with all the values 'one cell up', but partitioned by a different column?

Tags: sql

I'm making a table in sql which has all closed activities in it. A few of my columns are `Companyname` and `ActualEndDate`. 
The table is ordered by CompanyName and ActualEndDate desc.

I want to add a column with the date of the last activity per Company. So, if I have three activities for company A on `2018-01-01`, `2018-02-01` and `2018-02-12` (in column ActualEndDate), I want an extra column next to it where the row from 2018-01-01 is null in the new column, `2018-02-01` is `2018-01-01`, and `2018-02-12` is 2018-02-01.

I have no clue how to get this done as I cannot simply duplicate the column and move all values one up, because it has to be done per companyname.

Does anyone have any clue on how to get this done?

What I want:

```
Companyname         ActualEndDate     PreviousDate  
A                   2018-01-01         null  
A                   2018-02-01         2018-01-01  
A                   2018-02-07         2018-02-01  
B                   2018-01-01         null
B                   2018-02-01         2018-01-01
```

What I have:

```
Companyname         ActualEndDate      
A                   2018-01-01       
A                   2018-02-01        
A                   2018-02-07         
B                   2018-01-01         
B                   2018-02-01
```

I'm new to SQL so I'm sorry if my explanation is bad.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle,....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LAG()` is the right answer.  This is a SQL standard function and available in most databases.

However, the typical syntax is:

```
SELECT Companyname, ActualEndDate,
       LAG(ActualEndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Companyname ORDER BY ActualEndDate) as PreviousDate
FROM yourTable;
```

There is no reason to repeat the `PARTITION BY` columns in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is using window-functions - in your case `LAG()`

In case you are using SQL-Server, the solution would be:

```
SELECT Companyname
      ,ActualEndDate
      ,LAG(ActualEndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Companyname ORDER BY Companyname, ActualEndDate )
  FROM yourTable
```

Link for Oracle:  [LAG in Oracle](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php)

Link for SQL-Server: [LAG in SQL-Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Link for MySQL: [LAG in mySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/)

Link for PostgreSQL: [Window functions in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn't know about the lag function. Got it right now, thanks :)

Comment: @user11299833 If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).